# Cells merging (tabularx)

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I have a table and I need to merge cells there, but I don't know how exactly do it.

My code looks like this right now:

```
\documentclass{article}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[russian]{babel}   
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\begin{document}       
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}   
\hline    
 Разделы & & Страницы \\ \hline   
 Номер & Название & \\ \hline   
 1. & Отрасль применения &  \\ \hline   
 2. & Ответственные лица &  \\ \hline   
 3. & Нормативная база &  \\ \hline   
 4. & Материальная база &  \\ \hline   
 5. & Определения и сокращения &  \\ \hline  
 6. & Основная часть &  \\ \hline   
 7. & Конечные выводы, рекомендации &  \\ \hline   
\end{tabularx}   
\end{document}
```

It have to be like this:

[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Разделы}` and remove one ampersand (`&`).

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, how to merge cells in the right corner of the table (Страницы)  ?

Comment: Replace the `\hline` with `\cline{1-2}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following changes of your MWE (they considers all above comments and add design of table and column headers, for this the package `multirow` is needed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}% <---

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|c|}% <---
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Разделы}}% <--- 
        & \multirow{2}*{\textbf{Страницы}} \\ % <---
    \cline{1-2}
\textbf{Номер} & \textbf{Название}  &   \\ \hline% <---
 1. & Отрасль применения            &   \\ \hline
 2. & Ответственные лица            &   \\ \hline
 3. & Нормативная база              &   \\ \hline
 4. & Материальная база             &   \\ \hline
 5. & Определения и сокращения      &   \\ \hline
 6. & Основная часть                &   \\ \hline
 7. & Конечные выводы, рекомендации &   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]